# What is a varible produced through binary dimension reduction called?

Tags: functions, notation, index-notation

If I take *k* binary variables and reduce them to one *k*-long string variable consisting of zeros and ones. What would you call the new variable?

For example, for unit *i*, *xi1 = 1*, *xi2 = 0, xi3 = 0*, and *xi4 = 1*. So for that unit *i* above, the new variable's value would be 1001.

Is there a name for this type of variable? Maybe a "composite variable," or a "descriptive index", or a "binary-style index."

Comment: You have tacitly assumed the variables are ordered when you called them strings. Did you mean to do that? It's just unclear to me what distinction you're drawing between the ordered $k$ variables and $k$-long string variables.

Comment: Yes, the order matters for the variable type I have in mind. X_{i1} and X_{i2} are different variables so, 1000 would be different than 0100.

Comment: I think "binary encoded variable" is a good choice over "binary coded variable". It is less common and less likely to be interpreted as converting a yes/no (or other binary choice) variable to to 0/1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a *bit map* (bit vector, [bit array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array)) from the individual yes/no data points.

Internally in a computer program you can represent that as an integer in base $2$ and store it that way.